# Forcing node traffic to local network

Tags: nodes, private-network, bootnode

We would like to force all our local node traffic to use the local network instead of the internet to communicate between eachother. Any best practice to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To allow a node to connect to other nodes in the local network you will want to use the following flags:

```
--allow-private-ipv4: Always accept connecting to private IPv4 addresses.
--discover-local: Enable peer discovery on local networks.
```

As is explained in `polkadot --help`, those options are `Enabled by default for chains marked as "local" in their chain specifications, or when` --dev `is passed"`.

Moreover if you want to restrict connection only to certain peers, you should look into the `--reserved-nodes` and `--reserved-only` flags.

Comment: Would this still allow external connections over the internet though? I would like the nodes we are running only communicate local but still want other nodes to connect across the internet.

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't prevent internet traffic as long as your node is reachable on a public IP.